# How to create a admin report grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, reports

I am about to create an admin grid, which shows the report like 
>

> - take every single order from the beginning of the site
> - for every month we want to know how many total orders that were in
>     the following values:
>     [image: values]

and I assume the report like

> [image: grid result should like this]

Comment: Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi everyone, after a long time research i just found a query to build up the result. I am posting the sql query here.

```
SELECT sales_flat_order.entity_id AS entity_id, 
   CASE 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '0' AND '100.99' THEN '0-100.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '101' AND '150.99' THEN '101-150.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '151' AND '200.99' THEN '151-200.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '201' AND '250.99' THEN '201-250.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '251' AND '300.99' THEN '251-300.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '301' AND '350.99' THEN '301-350.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '351' AND '400.99' THEN '351-400.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '401' AND '450.99' THEN '401-450.99' 
       WHEN sales_flat_order.`grand_total` BETWEEN '451' AND '500.99' THEN '451-500.99' 
       ELSE '501+' 
   END AS 'order_range', 
   DATE_FORMAT(sales_flat_order.created_at, '%Y %b') AS 'Month', 
   CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(sales_flat_order.`grand_total`), 2)) AS 'Sales', 
   sales_flat_order.`grand_total` AS Amount, 
   COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id) AS 'Orders' 
FROM sales_flat_order 
GROUP BY MONTH,
     order_range 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(sales_flat_order.created_at, '%Y %m'),
     CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(order_range, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED)";
```

> Once again thank you for the leads.