# Magento 1.9 custom collection pagination not working in admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, collection, grid, pagination

I have created a custom grid to show a monthly wise report, But the pagination is not working with the Varien_Data_Collection . Please find the code snipet below from Grid.php

```
      $rows  = $connection->fetchAll($sql);//this row will return an array

        $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();

        foreach($rows as $row){
            $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
            $rowObj->setData($row);
            $collection->addItem($rowObj);
        }



        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
```

Comment: Why don't you define your collection as a resource model and get your collection in the standard Magento way for grid?

Comment: I wrote an sql query because i need a monthly report. For more info please this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222793/how-to-create-a-admin-report-grid/222823#222823

Answer (score 0):

The (non-abstract) base-class Varien_Data_Collection - although it does have the setPageSize and setCurPage methods, those are not reflected within the aggregation of the Iterator:

class Varien_Data_Collection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    ...

```
/**
 * Implementation of IteratorAggregate::getIterator()
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}

...
```

It will in any case return an ArrayIteator that has all objects. The load method doesn't change a thing here btw:

...

```
/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @return  Varien_Data_Collection
 */
public function loadData($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this;
}

...

/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @return  Varien_Data_Collection
 */
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this->loadData($printQuery, $logQuery);
}

...
```

The (non-abstract) base-class Varien_Data_Collection - although it does have the setPageSize and setCurPage methods, those are not reflected within the aggregation of the Iterator:

class Varien_Data_Collection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    ...

```
/**
 * Implementation of IteratorAggregate::getIterator()
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}

...
```

It will in any case return an ArrayIteator that has all objects. The load method doesn't change a thing here btw:

```
...

/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @return  Varien_Data_Collection
 */
public function loadData($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this;
}

...

/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @return  Varien_Data_Collection
 */
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this->loadData($printQuery, $logQuery);
}

...
```

I'd say this qualifies as a bug, as the public interface makes one assume that the magent collection object Varien_Data_Collection provides pagination while it does not.

I have not searched for a bug-report regarding this issue. The solution is to use another iterator for pagination, for example like outlined in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679839/367456) to [How to Paginate lines in a foreach loop with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1679559/367456) with PHP's [LimitIterator](http://php.net/limititerator):

```
/**
 * Class Varien_Data_Collection_Pagination
 *
 * Aggregates missing Pagination on Collection on getting the Iterator
 *
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
 */
class Varien_Data_Collection_Pagination implements IteratorAggregate
{
    /**
     * @var Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(Varien_Data_Collection $collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        $collection = $this->collection;
        if (FALSE === $size = $collection->getPageSize()) {
            return $collection;
        }

        $page = $collection->getCurPage();
        if ($page < 1) {
            return $collection;
        }

        $offset = $size * $page - $size;

        return new LimitIterator(new IteratorIterator($collection), $offset, $size);
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
$collectionIterator = new Varien_Data_Collection_Pagination($collection);

# [...] fill collection 

# set pagination:
$collection->setPageSize(3);
$collection->setCurPage(1);

echo iterator_count($collectionIterator); # 3 (int)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually i didn't understand anything, Sorry. What i have to do ?

Comment: @Radhu this is the basic structure. You need to check example which I set in lastly.

Comment: Varien_Data_Collection_Pagination , where we define this class ?